# Is it possibile to use extension functions in databinding?

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, extension-methods, android-databinding

I want to htmlize some data and set in the text view via data binding? Is it possible?

ie.If i have an extension function like this

```
 fun TextView.htmlText(txt: String?) {

txt.let {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        Html.fromHtml(txt, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
    } else {
        Html.fromHtml(txt)
    }
 
}
```

}

how can i put this extension function in databinding instead of this
`android:text="@{model.text}"`

Comment: Try making a custom binding adapter for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it using binding adapter

```
 @BindingAdapter("app:text")
@JvmStatic
fun htmlText(view: TextView, text: String?) {
    text?.let {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            view.text = Html.fromHtml(it.trim(), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
        } else {
            view.text = Html.fromHtml(it.trim())
        }
    }
}
```

like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

        <import type="android.text.Html" />

        <import type="android.os.Build" />

        <variable
            name="model"
            type="com.login.LoginViewModel" />

    </data>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text='@{Build.VERSION.SDK_INT> Build.VERSION_CODES.N?Html.fromHtml(model.text, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT):Html.fromHtml(model.text)}' />


</layout>
```

Comment: Please explain your solution. Answers which do not have an explanation and are only code get flagged as low effort.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.